# Restrict network requests to a single domain

Tags: ios, security, ios9

My app should only ever talk to my API hosted at `https://api.mycoolapp.com`. For security purposes, is it possible to set a rule (e.g. in App Transport Security) so my app automatically rejects any network requests not sent to `https://api.mycoolapp.com`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that as ATS only blocks domains based on their SSL configuration. If you desperately need this functionality, you could use `NSURLProtocol` to check every outgoing request and block it if it is going to an unexpected domain:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLProtocol

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift

This will be a lot of work tho.